# How to get messages from Gmail by using official gem

Tags: ruby

I'm using a `gmail` gem, but it will be deprecated from Aug 19, 2018.
So I tried to change Google offical gem.

I want to get all unread messages with a specific label like this.

```
gmail = Gmail.connect('example@gmail.com', 'password')
gmail.label('mylabel').find(:unread).each do |message|
   # to something
end
```

According to this document, I could get labels from my account.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/ruby

```
# Initialize the API
service = Google::Apis::GmailV1::GmailService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize

# Show the user's labels
user_id = 'me'
result = service.list_user_labels(user_id)
puts 'Labels:'
puts 'No labels found' if result.labels.empty?
result.labels.each { |label| puts "- #{label.name}" }
```

But only by reading a document in `rubydoc` I couldn't find out how to get messages by Gmail API.

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/GmailV1

How can I implement the function?
Where can I find the exmples for the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [found in the `GmailService` class](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/GmailV1/GmailService#list_user_messages-instance_method):

> **#list_user_messages**(user_id, include_spam_trash: nil, **label_ids: nil**, max_results: nil, page_token: nil, q: nil, fields: nil, quota_user: nil, user_ip: nil, options: nil)
>
> **Parameters**:
>
> - **user_id**
> - **label_ids** (*Array<String>, String*) — Only return messages with labels that match all of the specified label IDs.
> - ...

So to get messages with specific labels you call `list_user_messages`, with either a single label ID, or an array of label IDs:

```
service.list_user_messages(user_id, label_ids: "LID")
service.list_user_messages(user_id, label_ids: ["LID1", "LID2", "LID3"])
```

Comment: It seems I need to use `label_id` instead of `label_name`. I got the id by `service.list_user_labels(:me).labels.find{|l| l.name == 'label_name'}.id`, Thanks for the answer!